# What does the last element in a list point to in Scheme?

Tags: scheme

When I make a list in Scheme, what does the cdr of the last pair point to? Is it an 'empty word' or an 'empty list'? DrScheme doesnt mind `(cons 'a empty)` nor `(cons 'a '())`. Finally what is the difference between the empty word and the empty list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DrScheme doesn't mind your `cons`-ing, because `cons` can do more than just build lists. From the reference,

```
(cons a d) → pair?
  a : any/c
  d : any/c
```

which means that `cons` builds pairs. It's also perfectly legal to do

```
> (cons 1 2)
(1 . 2)
```

which is not a list, but which still lets you do

```
> (car (cons 1 2))
1
> (cdr (cons 1 2))
2
```

But anyways, the "empty word" and the "empty list " are the same object, as can be checked by

```
> (eq? empty '())
#t
```

Answer (score 1):

The cdr of the last pair points to '(), the empty list.

Comment: All lists are made up of a series of lists, each of length 2.  For example, (1 2 3) is actually a list of length 2: the first item is 1, and the second item is (2 3).  That inner list is also a list of length 2: the first item is 2, and the second item is (3).  That second item is actually a two-item list as well: the first item is 3, and the second item is ().

So, cons('a '()) returns ('a), because that is actually ('a . '()).

Answer (score 1):

The answer to all of your questions can be found if you evaluate the symbol `empty`.  It's defined to be equal to `'()`, the empty list, and this is what the last cdr points to.  To convince yourself, try this:

```
(cdr (list 1 2 3))
(cdr (cdr (list 1 2 3)))
(cdr (cdr (cdr (list 1 2 3))))
```

Comment: Although it answers a part of my question, I just realized that the cdr need not point to empty. I could have an improper list like (a b .d). Thanks anyway.